# Dart - How to convert nested Map<dynamic, dynamic> to Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart

I know how to convert `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` to `Map<String, dynamic>` using Map.from() method.
But what if I have unspecified number of nested Maps inside? How to convert all potential children as well from `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` to `Map<String, dynamic>`?

Comment: It will be easy to understand if you will add response map data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a recursive approach to this problem, where all map values of type `Map` are recursively converted as well.

```dart
// recursively convert the map
Map<String, dynamic> convertMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) {
  map.forEach((key, value) {
    if (value is Map) {
      // it's a map, process it
      value = convertMap(value);
    }
  });
  // use .from to ensure the keys are Strings
  return Map<String, dynamic>.from(map);
  // more explicit alternative way:
  // return Map.fromEntries(map.entries.map((entry) => MapEntry(entry.key.toString(), entry.value)));
}

// example nested map with dynamic values
Map<dynamic, dynamic> nestedMap = {
  'first': 'value',
  'second': {
    'foo': 'bar',
    'yes': 'ok',
    'map': {'some': 'value'},
  }
};

// convert the example map
Map<String, dynamic> result = convertMap(nestedMap);
print(result);
```

Comment: this is a great idea but i still get this error '"type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast"'. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The exact code I posted runs fine in [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev) for me. It sounds like it might have to do with how `Map.from` should be used.

Comment: Maybe it works for you if you explicitly parse the keys to Strings? I added the alternative return line where the entry keys are first mapped to Strings to the code above

Comment: ok it works fine now, there was a problem with nested parsing with freezed. thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Same answer as fravolt's but I was unable do put code in comments:

Map.forEach do not treats value by reference. You may change to:

```
// recursively convert the map
Map<String, dynamic> convertMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) {
    for (var key in map.keys) {
      if (map[key] is Map) {
        map[key] = convertMap(map[key]);
      }
    }  // use .from to ensure the keys are Strings
  return Map<String, dynamic>.from(map);
  // more explicit alternative way:
  // return Map.fromEntries(map.entries.map((entry) => MapEntry(entry.key.toString(), entry.value)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same answer but with additional condition for List

```
/// recursively convert the map tp Map<String,dynamic>
Map<String, dynamic> convertMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) {
  for (var key in map.keys) {
    if (map[key] is Map) {
      map[key] = convertMap(map[key]);
    } else if (map[key] is List) {
      map[key] = map[key].map((e) {
        if (e is Map) {
          return convertMap(e);
        }
        return e;
      }).toList();
    }
  }
  return Map<String, dynamic>.from(map);
}
```